# Syntax error on personally created GEM ( unexpected '\n', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.' (SyntaxError) )

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I encountered a problem with normalizing special characters (or accents in spanish). I created a GEM as a learning exercise  (on how to create, install and use a personal gem), but unfortunately I run into the error on the title, whenever I load the gem on another ruby file. The code below shows what my GEM is made of (i know the code is very bad but again it's a learning exercise).

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

module SpanishStringNormalizer

    class Normalizer

        def self.spanishNormalize (aString)

                while (aString.include? "á") ==true ||
                      (aString.include? "é") ==true ||
                      (aString.include? "í") ==true ||
                      (aString.include? "ó") ==true ||
                      (aString.include? "ú") ==true            do

                        aString ["á"]= "a" if aString.include? "á"
                        aString ["é"]= "e" if aString.include? "é"
                        aString ["í"]= "i" if aString.include? "í"
                        aString ["ó"]= "o" if aString.include? "ó"
                        aString ["ú"]= "u" if aString.include? "ú" 

                end #end of while

                return aString

        end #end of spanishNormalize

    end #end of class

end #end of module
```

However when I load this gem on another ruby file I get the following error

> /Users/Andre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in
>   `require': /Users/Andre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/Spanish String
>   Normalizer-0.0.0/lib/spanish_str_normalizer.rb:25: syntax error,
>   unexpected '\n', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.' (SyntaxError)

I keep trying different things but I haven't been able to solve it. Can someone help me identify where is the mistake i'm doing?

My GEM project can be found here: https://github.com/betogess506/Spanish-String-Normalizer

Comment: In my environment, it does not return an error.

Comment: Looks like the error is caused by configuration, a missing `gem build` or `gem install` step before you tested, or some code not shown here? @sawa: Although I am sure you are trying to show some "tough love", I think the comment comes across as overly negative towards the OP. IMO takes a while in professional coding before such robust comments are appreciated as helpful.

Comment: @NeilSlater Ok, I will rephrase it: Besides the error (which I cannot reproduce), there are many problems with the code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried your code but I can't reproduce the error on my system (neither using Ruby 2.0.0 or 1.9.3). However I think it's not worth bothering yourself troublshooting the problem, because your code can be written using just the [`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) method:

```
module SpanishStringNormalizer    
  def self.normalize(string)
    string.tr('áéíóú', 'aeiou')
  end
end

SpanishStringNormalizer.normalize('fóó')
# => "foo"
```

Comment: Your solution is even cleaner :) +1

Comment: This is cleaner code for doing the same as the gem, but does not solve the OPs problem. It is likely code not shown in the question that is the issue.

Comment: @toro2k I just run check your method in terminal and get output as follows. ruby version 1.8.7

SpanishStringNormalizer.normalize('fóó')
=> "fuuuu"

Comment: @toro2k thanks for your solution, it's obviously far cleaner and better than the one i came up with. I'm new to ruby and just wanted to  learn developing a gem for a recurring problem I had

Comment: @NeilSlater on the plus side though, less obfuscated code can make debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

As @sawa suggested, your code smells. Smelly smell smell. Here's how you could write it instead:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

module SpanishStringNormalizer
  REPLACEMENTS = {
    "á" => "a",
    "é" => "e",
    "í" => "i",
    "ó" => "o",
    "ú" => "u"
  }

  class Normalizer
    def self.spanishNormalize (aString)
      regex = Regexp.union(REPLACEMENTS.keys)
      aString.gsub(regex, REPLACEMENTS)
    end
  end
end
```

As for your original question, the error is not in your gem. I downloaded and required it and the requiring works just fine.

Comment: Also, your method `spanishNomalize` should really just be called `normalize` because `SpanishStringNormalizer` already implies that this is used for spanish. Another thing is that with this level of simplicity, you really don't need the nested `Normalizer` class.